# A better way to do this ? (putting string in stack in structure)

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct, stack

**All of the code works**, I just need to find a better (or at least different) way to do this :

The program should enable user to input 10 temepratures of air.
Temperatures are stored in a stack implemented via array.
There needs to be a function "checkTemperature"(in code: provjeriTemperature) which will receive a stack with the temperatures and inside it set value "check"/"review"(in code: provjeri) to "positive" or "negative"
After the function call, program should print info about temperature value and is it positive or negative, and also at the end make simple temperature average.

Now, i have done all that but you can see at the part of the code that looks pretty janky (its the reppetitive staircases).

```
#include <string>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAX 10

/*typedef struct{
float temperature[10];
char provjera[30];
} Temper;


typedef struct{
int vrh;
Temper elementi[MAX];

} Stog;
*/

typedef struct{ 
int vrh;
float temperature[10];
char provjera[10][9];
} Stog;


void ubaci (float x, Stog *pokStog){
if (pokStog->vrh == 0)
printf("Stack is full!");
else {
pokStog->vrh--;
pokStog->temperature[pokStog->vrh] = x;
}}


void provjeriTemperature (Stog *pokStog){
int indeks1;
int indeks2;
float avg=0;
float sum=0;

printf("\nStack:\n");
for(indeks1=pokStog->vrh; indeks1<=MAX-1; indeks1++){
        if(pokStog->temperature[indeks1]<0){


        pokStog->provjera[indeks1][0]='n';
            pokStog->provjera[indeks1][1]='e';
                pokStog->provjera[indeks1][2]='g';
                    pokStog->provjera[indeks1][3]='a';
                        pokStog->provjera[indeks1][4]='t';
                            pokStog->provjera[indeks1][5]='i';
                                pokStog->provjera[indeks1][6]='v';
                                    pokStog->provjera[indeks1][7]='n';
                                        pokStog->provjera[indeks1][8]='a';
        }

        else{
        pokStog->provjera[indeks1][0]='p';
            pokStog->provjera[indeks1][1]='o';
                pokStog->provjera[indeks1][2]='z';
                    pokStog->provjera[indeks1][3]='i';
                        pokStog->provjera[indeks1][4]='t';
                            pokStog->provjera[indeks1][5]='i';
                                pokStog->provjera[indeks1][6]='v';
                                    pokStog->provjera[indeks1][7]='n';
                                        pokStog->provjera[indeks1][8]='a';

    }
    sum+=pokStog->temperature[indeks1]; 
    }


for(indeks2=pokStog->vrh; indeks2<=MAX-1; indeks2++){

printf("%.2f    ", pokStog->temperature[indeks2]);
for(int indeks3=0;indeks3<9;indeks3++){

    printf("%c",pokStog->provjera[indeks2][indeks3]);   
}

printf("\n");

}
avg=sum/10;
printf("\n Prosjecna temperatura je: %.2f",avg);

}
main(){
    /*Temper unos;
    Stog mojStog;
    mojStog.vrh=MAX;

    printf("\n Unesite 10 temperatura: ");
    for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++){
        printf("\n %d. temperatura iznossi: ",i+1);
        scanf("%f", &unos.temperature);
        provjeriTemperature(unos,&mojStog);
    }

    ispis(&mojStog);
    */

    Stog mojStog;
    mojStog.vrh=MAX;
    float temperature;

        printf("\n Enter 10 temperatures: ");
    for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++){
        printf("\n %d. temperature is: ",i+1);
        scanf("%f", &temperature);
        ubaci(temperature,&mojStog);
    }
    provjeriTemperature(&mojStog);

}
```

Comment: You can use `memcpy()` from `string.h` instead of assigning characters one-by-one like `memcpy(pokStog->provjera[indeks1], "negativna", 9);`. Note that you cannot use `strcpy()` here because `pokStog->provjera[indeks1]` is only 9 character-long and using `strcpy()` will cause out-of-bound write of the terminating null-character.

Comment: You can use `fwrite(pokStog->provjera[indeks2], 1, 9, stdout);` instead of printing each characters one-by-one.

Comment: That indentation is downright dizzying. Each of those `pokStog` assignments should be at exactly the same level. "Repetitive staircases" is not the structure to use here.

Comment: OT: regarding: `main(){`  Regardless of what some (no compliant) compilers will allow you to use, there are only two valid signatures for `main()` they are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding:  1) Please consistently indent the code: Indent after each opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  Indenting each line in the body of an `if()` code block another 4 spaces makes for problems with readability.

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%f", &temperature);`  There are MANY ways for this statement to fail.  for robust code always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful and notify the user if it failed.  Suggest:  `if( scanf("%f", &temperature) != 1 ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for temperature failed"\n" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `printf("Stack is full!");`  this is output to `stdout`.  `stdout` is buffered.  So this (probably) will not be displayed on your terminal until either some input statement is executed or the buffer overflows, or the program ends.  Much better to write: `printf("Stack is full!\n");`  Notice the newline at the end of the data which causs the stream buffer `stdout` to be flush`.  Note: this statement is vulnerable to malicious attacks.  Suggest: `printf( "%s\n", "Stack is full!" );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("\n Prosjecna temperatura je: %.2f",avg);` This exhibits the same problems as: `printf("Stack is full!");` and should be corrected in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

for this kind of code:

```
        pokStog->provjera[indeks1][0]='n';
        pokStog->provjera[indeks1][1]='e';
            pokStog->provjera[indeks1][2]='g';
                pokStog->provjera[indeks1][3]='a';
                    pokStog->provjera[indeks1][4]='t';
                        pokStog->provjera[indeks1][5]='i';
                            pokStog->provjera[indeks1][6]='v';
                                pokStog->provjera[indeks1][7]='n';
                                    pokStog->provjera[indeks1][8]='a';
```

Must better to use:

```
strncpy( pokStog->provjera[indeks1], "negativna", 9);
```

However, I expect you want a char string, so suggest changing:

```
char provjera[10][9];
```

to

```
char provjera[10][10];
```

To allow room for the terminating NUL byte, then the code can be reduced to:

```
strcpy( pokStog->provjera[indeks1], "negativna" );
```

similar considerations exist for :

```
pokStog->provjera[indeks1][0]='p';
        pokStog->provjera[indeks1][1]='o';
            pokStog->provjera[indeks1][2]='z';
                pokStog->provjera[indeks1][3]='i';
                    pokStog->provjera[indeks1][4]='t';
                        pokStog->provjera[indeks1][5]='i';
                            pokStog->provjera[indeks1][6]='v';
                                pokStog->provjera[indeks1][7]='n';
                                    pokStog->provjera[indeks1][8]='a';
```

being reduced to:

```
strcpy( pokStog->provjera[indeks1], "pozitivna" );
```

If the above suggestion is followed, then this:

```
for(int indeks3=0;indeks3<9;indeks3++)
{
    printf("%c",pokStog->provjera[indeks2][indeks3]);   
}
```

can be reduced to:

```
printf( "%s\n", pokStog->provjera[indeks1] );
```